# Cant connect React to Graphcool backend

Tags: reactjs, graphcool

Im trying to get a basic React + Graphcool project setup.

Ive initialised the Graphcool backend so I can see the playground at: https://api.graph.cool/simple/v1/MY-KEY

I can run this query in the playground and see results:

```
query {
    allGroups {
        id
        description
    }
}
```

However I cant connect this to the React front-end. This is my index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

// GraphQL
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';

// Components
import App from './components/App/App';

const httpLink = new HttpLink({
    uri: 'https://api.graph.cool/simple/v1/MY-KEY',
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: httpLink,
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <App />
    </ApolloProvider>,
    document.getElementById('App'),
);
```

In App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import graphql from 'react-apollo';

const myQuery = gql`
    query {
        allGroups {
            id
            description
        }
    }
`;

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Application</h1>
            <h2>Groups:</h2>
        </div>
    );
};

// export default App;
export default graphql(myQuery)(App);
```

But I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _reactApollo2.default) is not a function
```

I don't know if this relevant or not but my IDE gives me the following error on the 'allGroups' line in App.js:

```
cannot query field "allGroups" on type "Query"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'd better  using a  graphcool play ground to test you query and mutation
. then connect to React.Otherwise, there are many detail to debug.
here is my  procedure

1. graphcool deploy  is ok?
2. go to playground  schema is ok?
3. query and  mutation  is ok?
4. configure apollo client and connect to React component.  is ok?
5. In the component  console.log(this.props.data)  is ok ?

   This is my flow.

And the most thing  when  you  add some schema and  resolvser, you must be add then to graphcool.yaml files. otherwise, graphcool can't find you schema and query method.

Answer (score 1):

thats graphql import error, lets try this

> In App.js:

```
 import { graphql, } from 'react-apollo';
```

Comment: Im still getting errors: Uncaught TypeError: _super.call is not a function. 4.js:sourcemap:12210 The above error occurred in the <Apollo(App)> component. Uncaught TypeError: _super.call is not a function. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'modules' of undefined

Comment: ok, apollo passes the data to props.data , there is no props in App component .. lets try to add the props and debug :  `const App = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Application</h1>
            <h2>Groups: {props.data}</h2>
        </div>
    );
};`

Comment: Im getting the white screen of death so nothing is rendered. I tried console logging props but notting is logged.

Comment: we have solved those two issues , now we might have 'naming' problem in index.js .. `ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root') // change this to something else than 'App'
)`

 help and do like on a my comment mate

Comment: No change... ;-(

Comment: hmm , we need to check who prevent those permissions calls , if this query worked in playground so no reason not working here as the resolver works fine . this is SSR application?

Comment: Sorry I don't know what a SSR application is! I didnt explicitly setup any permissions. Where are read permissions?

Comment: If I type in graphcool-framework into my terminal the playground launches in a browser. If I add /permissions to the end of the url then I get this error: Schema could not be fetched.
Please check if the endpoint 'https://api.graph.cool/simple/v1/MY-KEY/permissions' is a valid GraphQL Endpoint.

Comment: in graphcool.yml I have this: permissions:
  - operation: "*"

Comment: good , thats our problem here ,maybe not SSR( SSR-server side rendering you will need little differant 'client' )

Comment: what is `MY-KEY` stands for ? is that valid service id?

Comment: Yes Its a valid key - the playground opens up in my browser fine.

Answer (score 0):

[Is this your address?](https://api.graph.cool/simple/v1/MY-KEY)

[here is mine](https://api.graph.cool/simple/v1/cjaxudkum2ugf0127kok921bc)

can you see difference?